# flutter popuntil cannot refresh page

Tags: flutter

```
  Future<void> pressed() async {   
        final result = await Navigator.of(context).push(
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (_) => Page2(
     
        ),
      ),
    );
    if (result != null && result) {
      onRefreshPage(c); // this is the refresh function when come back from other page
    }
    return;
  }
```

In page 3, I use this to go back to page 1

```
onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).popUntil(ModalRoute.withName("/")),
```

page2:

```
 Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (_) => page3()),
        ModalRoute.withName("/"));
```

I am new in flutter.
I am from page1>page2>page3, after page3 hit the button it will directly go back to page1. However,
I want to update the list in page 1 after page3 come back. It does not work, pls help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're trying to use popUntil to navigate back to Page 1 from Page 3 in your Flutter app and refresh Page 1 when you return to it. However, the issue you're facing is that Page 1 is not being refreshed as expected.

One common approach to refresh a page when you return to it is to use the Navigator's pop method and pass data back to the previous page using a callback function. Here's a revised version of your code to achieve this:

In Page 3 (the page you want to return from to Page 1), when you want to go back to Page 1 and trigger a refresh:

```
onPressed: () {
  Navigator.of(context).pop(true); // Pass true to indicate that a refresh is needed
}
```

In Page 1, where you want to refresh the page:

```
Future<void> pressed() async {   
  final result = await Navigator.of(context).push(
    MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (_) => Page2(),
    ),
  );

  if (result != null && result) {
    // Check if a refresh is needed and perform the refresh
    onRefreshPage(c);
  }
}
```

Now, when you navigate back from Page 3 to Page 1 and pass true as the result, you can check for this value in Page 1 and trigger the refresh accordingly. This way, you can ensure that the page is refreshed when returning from Page 3.

Comment: is this pop to page2? since i push from page1>page2>page3

Comment: how about page 2 how to work with page 2

Answer (score 0):

You need some kind of communication between page 3 and page 1 when page 3 pop's store a value and check in page 1 if the value is updated than refresh the page. If true (page gets refreshed) then reset the value.

Comment: anyone can help

Comment: How can I popuntil to the first page with true return